# ASN Lookup alias not functioning

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to use the following alias in my .bashrc profile:

```
alias ip2asn="IP=$(dig $1 a +short);whois -h v4.whois.cymru.com " -v $IP""
```

The command itself works without issue, however when I create the alias in .bashrc and try to source ~./bashrc I get the following output:

```
$ source .bashrc
bash: alias: -v: not found
bash: alias: k.root-servers.net.: not found
bash: alias: d.root-servers.net.: not found
bash: alias: c.root-servers.net.: not found
bash: alias: e.root-servers.net.: not found
bash: alias: f.root-servers.net.: not found
bash: alias: m.root-servers.net.: not found
bash: alias: g.root-servers.net.: not found
bash: alias: b.root-servers.net.: not found
bash: alias: j.root-servers.net.: not found
bash: alias: i.root-servers.net.: not found
bash: alias: h.root-servers.net.: not found
bash: alias: a.root-servers.net.: not found
bash: alias: l.root-servers.net.: not found
```

I noticed that the bash shell appears to be retaining the $IP variable even after execution of the alias. I'm unsure how to response this issue.

Any advise?
Thanks,
--techno-shaman

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems in your declaration. First of them is that you need to escape the inner double quotes `"`, otherwise you'd be closing and reopening them. The second problem is that your `$IP` is expanding on the alias *declaration* instead of when you use it.

About `$IP` surviving the alias execution: an alias is nothing more then commands being typed for you. You should not use variables at all or create a subshell - enclosing everything with `()`.

```
alias ip2asn='(IP=$(dig $1 a +short);whois -h v4.whois.cymru.com -v "$IP")'
```

Anyway I think this won't work as you expect, alias doesn't receive parameters like that, this `$1` won't work. It sounds you need a function:

```
ip2asn() {
  whois -h v4.whois.cymru.com -v "$(dig "$1" a +short)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the previous answer seems to have a bug - the first double quote belongs before the -v and, additionally, the -v part needs a leading space.

furthermore, the $(dig...) is not required as the IP address is being given on the cmd line, thus,

> function ip2asn() { whois -h v4.whois.cymru.com " -v $1"; }

works well for me.

example:

> ip2asn 159.135.32.14
>
> AS      | IP               | BGP Prefix          | CC | Registry | Allocated  | AS Name
>
> 53824   | 159.135.32.14    | 159.135.32.0/20     | US | arin     | 2015-10-21 | LIQUIDWEB, US

however, if the $(dig...) IS left in, then the function may be renamed (and used) as domainName2asn , eg.,

> function domainName2asn() { whois -h v4.whois.cymru.com " -v $(dig $1 A +short)"; }
>
> domainName2asn redhat.com
>
> AS      | IP               | BGP Prefix          | CC | Registry | Allocated  | AS Name
>
> 31976   | 209.132.183.105  | 209.132.182.0/23    | US | arin     | 2004-01-22 | REDHAT-0, US

yes, i know this is a very old thread :J